# How to get user from db_link using Oracle

Tags: oracle, dblink

I am struggling with dblinks in Oracle.

I have an `external schema` that is linked to production and test system as well. Calling both by `stored procedures` works fine.

Inside each stored procedure I want to execute command like,

```
select sys_context('userenv','instance_name') as user from dual
```

to determine environment (just for fun, please don't ask me why). But the only user I get is the one of the external Schema. Is there a way to get correct user?

Comment: You want to get the procedure owner, and/or the instance that schema is in, on the remote (prod/test) database?

Comment: when i run command 'select sys_context('userenv'..' on production DB directly i'm getting result 'prod_user' and 'test_user' on test system respectively. same command on external schema delivers  'ext_user' in any case. if i use procedure for calling prod system on external schema i also want to get result 'prod_user' and not 'ext_user'. i hope you understand my english.

Comment: I'm still not sure if you are looking for the owner of the procedure, or the user you're connected to the remote database as, or the instance name for that database. Are you really querying `instance_name`?

Comment: have you tried select sys_context('userenv','current_schema') from dual